# How does BRIEF produce consistent keypoints with random sampling?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm reading through [BRIEF](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=A6AEA9D4D45499E18BB785259C90ACED?doi=10.1.1.227.8658&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and one point isn't clear to me. If we are randomly sampling the pixel-vs-pixel tests, how is it that we obtain a reproducible descriptor?

**EDIT**

This is a duplicate. Find question with answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69951/are-location-in-brief-feature-descriptor-reused)

Comment: I'm used to writing longer, more detailed questions on here, but if you're someone who knows the answer to this one, you probably understand the question despite the brevity.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if they came up with a random pixel patch vs pixel patch set of points and they used this to train their system.  The system then recognizes different transformations by looking at the database of transformations and seeing how the transformations would affect the match.  It then picks the transformation with the best score (lowest Hamming distance).  The random pixel locations are only random once during the system design.

Comment: Yeah I got a response on Reddit saying that the same set of random points is used. It just seems weird to me, as then I'd expect they would make more of a point about where to find these points so that all implementations of it look the same.

Comment: Here is the response! https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69951/are-location-in-brief-feature-descriptor-reused